# how to change the content of a header cell in dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, innerhtml

I'm using the [dataTables](http://datatables.net) plugin

On my sortable columns I want to replace the column text with a button.

However doing this:

```
$( oSettings.aoColumns[i].nTh).text();
```

I can retrieve the text of the respective column, BUT

```
$( oSettings.aoColumns[i].nTh).text("some text");
$( oSettings.aoColumns[i].nTh).html("<a href='#'>some button</a>");
```

Does not do anything.

Can somebody tell me why I can retrieve info from a cell but not edit it's content? Not necessarily a dataTables question, but maybe someone has run into something similar.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT: This is the solution:**
Inside your table call specify, which columns should be sortable = these get a *.jqmSorter* class

```
  "aoColumns": [
    /* Select */    {"bSortable": false },
    /* Type */      {"sClass": "jqmSorter"},
    /* From */      {"bSortable": false },
    /* Status */    {"bSortable": false },
],
```

Then call the *fnHeaderCallback* in which I'm replacing the header cell content with a JQM button:

```
   "fnHeaderCallback": function( nHead ) {      
       $(nHead).closest('thead').find('.jqmSorter').each( function () {
          var sortTitle = $(this).text(),
          sortButton = 
             $( document.createElement( "a" ) ).buttonMarkup({
                  shadow: false,
                  corners: false,
                  theme: 'a',
                  iconpos: "right",
                  icon: "ui-icon-radio-off"
                  })
             sortButton.find('.ui-btn-text').text(sortTitle);
             $(this).html( sortButton )
             sortButton.addClass("colHighTrigger");             
             });
       }
```

Comment: Do you want to do this when the datatable is rendered or you want to do it while rendering itself?

Comment: It should only happen once, when the datatable is rendered. The button is just for visual appreance (Jquery Mobile icon-only button, which I'm switching icon-classes on depending on sorting order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

While defining [`table columns`](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) (define if you not doing it already), and use the `sClass` attribute of the table column definition (which is in JSON).

After this, that class will be applied to the table column.

After this, use the `callback` function of datatables : [`fnRowCallback`](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks)

and in this, set the html as

```
$(nRow, '.your_class').html('Your HTML Values');
```

This will be called when each row of the table is rendered.

If you don't want it to do on each row, you can control that with an if-condition.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I used fnHeaderCallBack though. You might want to change this in your answer, too. Last question. Do you know who to select the header cells in a two row header. The solution above only grabs the first header row.

Comment: found that, too. All set. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fnRender` in your `aoColumns` settings, use it to return HTML code for that specific cell, drop downs, checkboxes, anything you want will work there.

```
"aoColumns": [
    /*Col 1*/
    {
     "mData": "RowID",
     "bSortable": false,
     "sClass": "jqmSorter",
     "fnRender": function(obj){
                     return "<input id='" + obj.aData.RowID + "' type='button' value='myval'/>"
                 }
    },
    /*Col 2*/
    {
     "bSortable": false,
     "sClass": "jqmSorter",
     "fnRender": function(obj){
                     return "<input id='" + obj.aData.RowID + "' type='button' value='myval'/>"
                 }
    }
]
```