# How to add dynamic column headers to jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add the dynamic column header to data table  ,Here is my code  for datatable initialisation:

```
var $table=$('#MSRRes').dataTable
( {
        "bFilter": false,                         
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "ajax" :{
                    url: 'getResult.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        formData:postData,
                        formName:'afscpMsr',
                        action:'advanceSrch'
                    }

                }
});
```

Following code is for static intialisation of table column header :
    
       
           Customer Name
           Feature Order No
           NCP Account Number
           Mcn Code
           Sales Person
           Due Date
(DD/MM/YYYY)
           No. of SUPs
           Zonee Id
            Details

The following code is ajax call to get the datatable result display along with the column names to be display: $result is in json format,$colcond='cust_name,cust_no,mcn_no,sales_contact_name,order_no,COUNT(sup_id),due_date,z.zoned_from_id';

```
 $newarray = array(
                "draw"            => 1,
                "recordsTotal"    => sizeof($result),
                "recordsFiltered" => sizeof($result),
                "data"            => $result,
                "column"          => $colCond   
            );

            echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Comment: seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412443/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-header-cell-in-datatables)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `jquery-ui`, hence removing the tag. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, jquery ui is not there, Its related to jquery datatables

Answer (score 1):

```
var aryColTableChecked = ["column00", "column01", "column02",    "column03","column00","column00","column00","column00"];
var aryJSONColTable = [];

for (var i=0; i < aryColTableChecked.length; i++ ) {
      aryJSONColTable.push({
                "sTitle": aryColTableChecked[i],
                "aTargets": [i]
       });
};
```

Include this in data table definition :

```
 var $table=$('#MSRRes').dataTable
( {
    "bFilter": false,                         
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "ajax" :{
                url: 'getResult.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    formData:postData,
                    formName:'afscpMsr',
                    action:'advanceSrch'
                }

            },
  "aoColumns": aryJSONColTable
});

});
```

Comment: this solution is working for me, for more information check  this link : http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/11637/aocolumndefs-with-dynamic-column-data